# How to use BETWEEN keyword in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, between

How do i use BETWEEN key word in Entity Framework?

This is my SQL query

```
    SELECT *
  FROM [HRM].[dbo].[meals]
  WHERE SHIFTCODE = 'Normal'
  AND 12.59 BETWEEN [STAR TIME] AND [STAR TIME]+DURATION/10;
```

This is my Entity Framework Code.

```
HRMEntities HRM = new HRMEntities();
            meal ml = HRM.meals.SingleOrDefault(p => p.SHIFTCODE == "Normal");
```

value 12.59 can be a variable

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `>=` and `<=` with `DateTime` to get a range.

```
HRMEntities HRM = new HRMEntities();
meal ml = HRM.meals.SingleOrDefault(p => p.SHIFTCODE == "Normal" 
                                    && p.StartTime <= yourTime 
                                    && (p.StartTime + duration) >= yourtime);
```

Comment: shouldn't the checks be inverted? p.StartTime <= yourTime && (p.StartTime+duration) >= yourtime); ?

Comment: @YngveB.Nilsen, yup, mixed it while typing the answer

Comment: Thanks Guys and another thing, basically StartTime is stored as DECIMAL and duration stored as INT in SQL, Since they deal with time is there any easy way to get rid of values like 12.75 for an examples,
 STAR TIME= 12.45
DURATION = 30 // 30 mins
START TIME + DURATION/10 = 12.75
if myTime is 11.05 it gives a wrong feedback

Comment: Not really clear about your new query, but you can get the `int` part of decimal using `((int) StartTime) + duration`

Comment: you may look into [DateTime.AddMinutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addminutes.aspx) method

Comment: yes then i changed the code as below.... but again it gives an error by saying DATETIME.PARSE is not recognized by LINQ
http://i47.tinypic.com/2emep1y.png

Comment: @Keizer, you may post your current problem in a new question with much more detail, because its getting off the topic. Starting a new thread with your problem may gives you better answers

Comment: Using an operator on a column causes this query to be non-sargable.  Instead it should be `p.StartTime >= yourtime - duration`.